# What could be the reason for this error 1241 on MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to run this query on a large number of data but facing this operand error, when I run it with only one lead it works fine but not all together any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    records 
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                records.id,
                lead(records.speed,1) OVER (ORDER BY records.run_date_time) != records.speed AS chk,
                lead(records.user_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY records.run_date_time) != records.user_id AS chk2,
                lead(records.error_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY records.run_date_time) != records.error_id AS chk3,
                lead(records.job_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY records.run_date_time) != records.job_id AS chk4,
                lead(records.machine_id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY records.run_date_time) != records.machine_id AS chk5 
            FROM
                records) AS x 
        WHERE
            (
                NOT (chk, chk2, chk3, chk4, chk5)
            ) 
            AND (
                records.id = x.id
            )
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Your nested select statement doesn't define any columns to select

Comment: `SELECT 1` will return simply 1

Comment: If I change it for example to id still get the same error